# django ListView - Sort queryset by the order of mptt-TreeForeignKey field

Tags: django, listview, django-mptt

I have the following two models.

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=75,null=False,blank=False, unique=True)
    parent=TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

and

```
class ProductGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False, blank=False)
    category=TreeForeignKey('category.Category', null=False,blank=False)
```

I have set an order for the categories through the admin panel.

I need to get the `ProductGroup` objects sorted in the same order through its `ListView` sub class.

I have tried,

```
class ProductGroupList(ListView):
    model=ProductGroup
    ordering = ['category']
```

but this lists the objects in the order of id of `Categories`.

Is there a way to specify the order specified in the `mptt` tree?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937130/django-mptt-order it can help you

Comment: I had a look at that thread, but it talks about the ordering of objects of the same class. Thanks.